# BASH -How easily determine how much is in a variable number of such characters

Tags: bash

how easily determine how much is in a variable number of such characters

```
VAR="ddfasf♣dsdad ♣ as dsdsd  ♣  sadsd     ♣ df"
echo $VAR # result 4 

VAR="♣♣ as dsd♣sd  ♣  s♣adsd     ♣ df"
echo $VAR # result 5
```

I tried this but it does not work :-(

```
echo "$(echo $VAR | tr -dc ♣ | wc -c)"
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
chars=${VAR//[!♣]}
echo "${#chars}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The option to delete all **but** the specified chars in tr is -C

```
  $(echo $VAR | tr -dC ♣ | wc -c)
```